# Network/url logging Linux

Tags: linux, networking

After some research on the internet I couldnt find an appropriate tool for my task. I am looking for a linux based networking tool like iptraf but with the ability to see which url was exactly requested (in and out).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this is for superuser (hint: you want wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: thank you. Do you have any idea if there something not that bloated...a smaller,thinner solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux you can use the `tcpdump` command to capture traffic, including all the data, to a file.